# Kubernetes change parallelism number in a CronJob

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying out parallelism on Kubernetes for the first time. Currently the job does some actions for each user in a SQL database. I have setup a work queue so all jobs know what user to process.

Currently my CronJob Yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: messagequeue
spec:
  schedule: "0 1 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      parallelism: 5 <-- i need to change this based on user count
      template:
        metadata:
          name: messagequeue
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: c
            image: *image*
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I use 'parallelism: 5' because i have 5 active users in the database. Is there a way to change the parallelism count on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

update concurrent policy to ALLOW as given below.

```
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
```

Comment: Sorry, not exactly what i am looking for. I want to change the parallelism amount. So if i have 2 users the parallelism is 2. If i have 20 users in the database the parallelism should be 20. It there a way to do this?

Comment: schedule another cronjob to check the number of users in the database and then update the parallelism on the other cronjob..

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. But how do i update the cronjob.yml with a parallelism variable?

Comment: using rbac. you need to bind the service account to the pod/cronjob to update the cronjob yaml